# How to create a stack of different types of variable?

Tags: c++

Can someone help me how to create a stack that handles different types of variable. I have a BNF grammar that i need to push into stack and below are the things that i need to push into stack

1) +,-,/,*

2) integers - 0,1,2..9

3) characters - a,b..z,A,B..Z

4) $ Sign, Parenthesis (open, close), underscore

I am not sure if my below attempt would satisfy all of the above. Please correct me if i am wrong.

```
stack<int,string>mystack
```

Comment: You need a class that can hold any of these types as template argument Check out boost::variant.http://theboostcpplibraries.com/boost.variant

Comment: @rakeshdn thank you for pointing me right direction

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use polymorphism and push dynamic types onto your stack.  This can either be in the form of something like boost.variant, or a simple class hierarchy and store the items in the stack by *smart* pointer.  That is not an exhaustive list.

C++ doesn't support, as a core language item, dynamic variables.  You create them using techniques like virtual functions and inheritance, or type erasure.